# Adding Sentry 2 config in Workbench Package

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I am using laravel 4.1 and working on my own package in workbench. I added extra repo (sentry 2) in my package composer.json. Sentry is working properly but I can't override config by loading config files from workbench/package/name/src/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry/config.php

My service Provider looks like that:

```
    public function boot()
{
    // https://coderwall.com/p/svocrg
    $this->package('package/name');

    $config_path = __DIR__ . "/../../config/packages/cartalyst/sentry";
    $this->app['config']->package('cartalyst/sentry', $config_path, 'cartalyst/sentry');

    $this->app->register('Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider');

    include __DIR__.'/../../routes.php';
}

        public function register()
{
    $this->app->booting(function()
    {
        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('Sentry', 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry');
    });
}
```

When I override something in config.php (workbench/package/name/src/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry/config.php) I still get things from vendor/cartalyst/sentry/src/config/config.php. How to properly load config in workbench package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't because as explained at official cartalyst sentry website "sentry is third party"

but you still can do some trick in your composer file in workbench.

at your composer.json in workbench :

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "php artisan app:sentry" /* add your own command which organize to create your own sentry configuration (remember mkdir cartalyst/sentry/config.php store to app/config/packages) */
        ],
        // more
    },
```

this mean, when your package in installing, your own command (e.g : php artisan app:sentry) will be executed

hope this help you...

## **Or, alternatively (more simple)**

in your composer scripts key add :

```
"php artisan config:publish --package=cartalyst/sentry"
```

and then, at boot method in your PackageServiceProvider,
set your own configuration.
for example :

```
public function boot()
{
    // for change user sentry model
    \Config::set('sentry::config.user.model', 'Vendor\Package\YourUserModel');
}
```

I think this is more simplest way. :)

Answer (score 1):

Example below show how i add config override of Basset in my package(workbench). You have to put this code in your `register` method in you service provider.

```
// Get config loader
$loader = $this->app['config']->getLoader();

// Add package namespace with path set base on your requirement
$loader->addNamespace('basset',__DIR__.'/../config/basset');

// Load package override config file
$configs = $loader->load($this->app['config']->getEnvironment(),'config','basset');

// Override value
$this->app['config']->set('basset::config',$configs);
```