# Laravel: Set Auth config for Package

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, package, config

I am creating my own package and I want to add Auth only for my package using a different table that the app auth table.

I can't found the way to override the app `auth.table` config only for my package.
Searching I found [this solution](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=57743#p57743), that change the config on the fly.

In my code:

```
class EasytranslateServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    [...]

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('revolistic/easytranslate');

        // add the packages routes
        include __DIR__.'/../../routes.php';

        // doesn't work 
        $this->app['config']['auth'] =  \Config::get('easytranslate::auth');
    }

    [...]
}
```

But it doesn't work, look like the Auth module is reading the configuration before the package creation or `boot()` function call.

If I do:

```
class EasytranslateServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    [...]

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('revolistic/easytranslate');

        // add the packages routes
        include __DIR__.'/../../routes.php';

        // doesn't work 
        $this->app['config']['auth'] =  \Config::get('easytranslate::auth');

        // show that the changes was made
        print_r($this->app['config']['auth']);
    }

    [...]
}
```

I get that the config was changed, but the Auth model is still taking the table name from the app auth config file.

I am using the last version of Laravel, any idea how I can accomplish it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this solution works i found my error i should to namespace my model in my package auth file like that

```
'model' => 'Revolistic\Easytranslate\User',
```

Cheers

Comment: You could do this in case you want to override others package config. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23856444/547552